# Script in GitLab CICD escape space character

Tags: shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a variable defined in .gitlab-ci.yml as

```
Filter: "-BUGS +AB"
```

When I try to access the variable under the script tag, it's formatted as

```
Filter: "=BUGS''+AB"
```

It's escaping the space character as ' ' which is causing my mvn command to crash.

Things tried:
The only way I could make it work is by hardcoding the value as '=BUGS +AB'. However, this cannot be parameterized as anything under '' will not get evaluated

I need to use the value of FILTER as -Dmetafilter=$FILTER in mvn command

Comment: what is your runner executor ?

Comment: runner is running in a linux container

Answer (score 0):

The only way it worked was:

```
"${FILTER:-"-BUGS"}"
```